# Knockout and Kendo Datetimepicker resets date to today when changing time

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js, kendo-ui

I have page that uses the Kendo DateTimePicker with the input bound to a Knockout Observable.  I am using knockout-kendo.js for the bridging.

As you can see in this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/raedwa01/gscktjr2/), I set up the observable with today's date time at initialization. I later set the value (as if it was loaded from an ajax retrieval, I just didn't want to deal with the echo api on JSFiddle)

```
var SchedulerAppointmentModel = function () {
    var self = this,
        saved = [],
        initComplete = false;
    self.StartDateTime = ko.observable(moment().format("MM/DD/YYYY hh:mm A"));
    self.StartDateTime(moment("10/23/2014 1:30 PM").format("MM/DD/YYYY h:mm A"));
};
```

The problem is, if I change the time in my drop down box, the date resets to today.  I wanted to leave the date alone.

I think it has something to do with setting the kendoDateTimePicker in code and not in html.  I think if i could somehow set the max later, it would work.

Comment: It's actually not setting the date for me if I change time - which browser are you using?  The only time it resets the date for me is if the date is invalid (put in an invalid date, change time)

Comment: I was able to do this in both Chrome and IE.  How did you change the time, by using the time picker or manually?  When i use the time picker, it always reset the date to today for me.

Comment: I am using chrome and changing with the time picker.  I will try again.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you still need an answer, but...

I see you've pulled in the knockout-kendo library. With that there is no need to manually initialize the dateTimePicker. You can simply use the binding that comes with that library:

```
<input id="appt-start-datetime" value="0" data-bind="kendoDateTimePicker: StartDateTime" />
```

[Fiddle Updated](http://jsfiddle.net/gscktjr2/4/)